# How best to create object variables from a method

Tags: python, class, oop, object, design-patterns

What is the best way to set object variables that are set by a method? Is the methodology below where `self.toppings` is first defined in `__init__()` and then the value is set in the `select_toppings()` method a good practice on how to set the `self.toppings` variable? Please let me know if you have better suggestions. Thanks.

```
class Pizza:

    def __init__():
        self.toppings = None 

    def select_toppings(input):
        self.toppings = input
```

Comment: There are `getter` and `setter` methods too which you can look into

Comment: Your code is good practice. It will allow a developer who reads your code to know what instance attributes exist by looking at the constructor only. On the other hand it is uncommon to have methos that only sets an attribute in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `toppings` directly to the constructor. (Don't use [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) as a variable name since it's a python builtin function)

```
class Pizza:

    def __init__(self, toppings):
        self.toppings = toppings

pz = Pizza('cheese')
print(pz.toppings)
```

The output will be `cheese`

Comment: Does this principle apply to larger classes? Isn't it going to be putting a lot of work into __init__()? Thanks.

Comment: `__init__` is meant for that. You can pass your default arguments you want to instantiate class with in `__init__`, and then work with them in other instance methods, (unless your usecase is different?)

Answer (score 3):

The main question is: what happens when an honest programmer writes:

```
pizza = Pizza()
pizza.do_something()
```

and `do_something()` needs `self.toppings != None`?

Remember: the role of the constructor is to properly initialize the object. All mandatory fields should be initialized at the end of the construction.

If the initialization of the object gets too complex (I would say: as soon as the constructor does more than just assigning values to fields), use a [creational pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern). Example with a factory:

```
class Pizza:
    @staticmethod
    def create(topping_list):
        toppings = Toppings(topping_list)
        return Pizza(toppings)

    def __init__(self, toppings):
        self._toppings = toppings

    ...
```

Or a builder:

```
class PizzaBuilder:
    def __init__(self):
        self._toppings = DEFAULT_TOPPINGS
        self._size = DEFAULT_SIZE

    def build(self):
        return Pizza(self.toppings, self._size)

    def toppings(self, toppings):
        self._toppings = toppings
        return self

    def size(self, size):
        self._size = size
        return self

class Pizza:
    def __init__(self, toppings, size):
        self._toppings = toppings
        self._size = size
```

You can create all combinations you need:

```
pizza1 = PizzaBuilder().build() # default pizza
pizza2 = PizzaBuilder().size(10).build() # big pizza with default toppings
pizza3 = PizzaBuilder().toppings(t1).build() # ...
```

An advantage of creational patterns is that your objects are fully initialized and are, in most cases, immutable. To put it in simple terms, setters and getters are separated and the design of your program gets cleaner.

Comment: Hi, thats a nice way to separate the builder and pizza class. However I am having trouble understanding how can we link the `PizzaBuilder()` and `Pizza()`?

Comment: They should be in the same module. The implicit link is that `PizzaBuilder.build` returns a `Pizza`. You can add a `@staticmethod   def builder(): return PizzaBuilder()` to the `Pizza` class if you want. Second example would be: `Pizza.builder().size(10).build()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way you can set using `property`

```
class Pizza:
    def __init__(self):
        self._toppings = None

    def get_toppings(self):
        print("get_toppings called!")
        return self._toppings

    def set_toppings(self, x):
        print("set_toppings called!")
        self._toppings = x

    toppings = property(get_toppings, set_toppings)

margherita = Pizza()
margherita.set_toppings("mozzarella cheese")
print(margherita.get_toppings())

# outputs 
mozzarella cheese
```

One pitfall of having no `set` and `get` method is this, I hope you can see how it causes a problem of changing the variables.

```
class Pizza:

    def __init__(self, toppings, dough):
        self.toppings = toppings
        self.pizza = toppings + ', ' + dough

pz = Pizza('cheese', 'flour')
pz.toppings = "chicken"
print(pz.toppings)
print(pz.pizza)

# outputs 
chicken
cheese, flour
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the tip.